# How to add view to all layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

After completing the app with so many screens, I got a requirement for download status. Basically I need to show a status view at the top of all screens pushing all contents down. Is there an easy way where I can apply this change globally ?

Thank you

Comment: Create a `BaseActivity` and inherit it from all the Activities . then Add/Remove the View to Root layout at runtime in base Activity whenever required.. You might have to change Some of the layout file if root layout is not the same..

Comment: Thank you , if you put it as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered in comments above for sake of closing putting it as an answer.
To have a consistent View in All Activities you can create a `BaseActivity` and have it extends by all your Activities.
In your case the `View` will be part of layout `hierarchy` vertically since you have to push down the content once its visible.